# aop with spring on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, aop

I'm trying to do a progarm small with spring

```
<bean
    id="mybean" 
    class="com.spr.main.Persona"
    p:name="Peter" 
    p:age="33" 
    p:address="LA" 
    p:company="Googel" 
    p:email="Peter@google.com"
/>

<bean id="logger" class="com.spr.main.Log" />

  <aop:config>
    <aop:aspect ref="logger">
        <aop:pointcut id="testPointcut"
                      expression="execution(* com.spr.main.Person.toString(..)) and target (bean)" />
        <aop:before method="logInfo" pointcut-ref="testPointcut" arg-names="bean"/>
        <aop:after-returning method="logWarning" pointcut-ref="testPointcut" arg-names="bean"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

the bean work fine, but aop doesn´t show the log messaga, this is the Log class:

```
public class Log 
{

public static void logInfo()
{
    Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName()).log(Level.INFO, "Info Message...");
}

public static void logWarning()
{
    Logger.getLogger(Log.class.getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Warning Message...");
}
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve through the code? the AOP config looks bit confusing to me. The execution expression is against Log class and the aop advice methods are also defined in Log class. It is bit odd to have a class trying to intercept itself isn't it?

Comment: this is only a test in orde to learn a bit the spring, and sorry execution(* com.spr.main.Log.toString(..)) is execution(* com.spr.main.Person.toString(..))